# How can I pull the slug of a custom taxonomy and output it in a class?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

This is the file I'm working with:

```
    <?php
$class ='';
foreach ($consoles as $console) {
$class .= $console->slug . ' ';
} 
?>
<div id="<?php the_id(); ?>" class="<?php echo $class ?>>
Content
</div>




<?php
$consoles = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'consoles' );
$separator = ", ";
$output = '';

if ( ! empty( $consoles ) ) {
if ( ! is_wp_error( $consoles ) ) {
echo '<li><span>Platforms:</span> ';
foreach( $consoles as $term ) {
$output .= esc_html( $term->name ) . $separator;
} echo trim($output, $separator);
echo '</li>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code, there is so much irrelevant code that is distracts one from the actual issue

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just get the taxonomies you need with wp_get_object_terms, and than do something like

```
$class ='';
foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    $class .= $genre->slug;
}
```

Do this for each of your taxonomies,than just echo $class.

Comment: This is really close, however the first post doesn't output the taxonomy, but the second does, but it's wrong, that taxonomy should be for the first one. Each taxonomy on a post should be for the one before it. Also how can I add a space inbetween if there's more than one?

Comment: `$class .= $console->slug . ' ';` I managed to space them with this, so the main problem now is that each post is showing the taxonomy of the post before.

Comment: You should put <?php
$consoles = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'consoles' ); at the beginning of your code - in your current code $consoles is undefined at the beginning.